# How to deploy node_modules folder to production server?

Tags: php, node.js, npm, bower, node-modules

I making a **very simple website** (like pastebin) in PHP (LAMP server). This site uses jquery and bootstrap. I was using `bower` earlier, but I want to switch to using `npm` instead.

My directory structure is like this:

- public

  - html

    - index.php
    - node_modules

      - jquery

        - dist

          - jquery.js
        - plus *dozens of needless folders*
      - bootstrap

        - ...

When I was using bower, I used to upload the whole bower_components folder to my FTP server. My node_modules folder is pretty large and contains hundreds of files and so I'm not sure if I should be uploading it?

I guess I can just upload package.json and run `npm install` on the command line of my webserver after uploading, but will exposing node_modules folder to the public pose potential security risks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `node_modules` folder should be in your `.gitignore` -if you are using git-. And no, you don't upload the whole folder. You, as you say, run `npm install`. This also applies to **bower**, you shouldn't upload the `bower_components` folder, you should run the command in your server.

As for the other part of the question, you shouldn't either expose `node_modules`. What you do is use some task manager or some bundler (gulp, grunt, webpack) and create a bundled (or concatted) version of your files (css and js). Once you have this file, that's what you expose. That's what you include in your index, for example `<script src="dist/bundle.min.js"></script>`

Comment: So node_modules will be filled with `npm install`. I'm going to try it out with babel (nothing else), which means about 14 MByte in this folder on my dev machine. This will be also on the production machine, right? Is this necessary? If I have many independent solutions using babel on this machine, each would have that folder with that size? Is it the same as it is with composer and the vendor dir? Although it gets only used to transpile the JS - nothing in node_modules gets used by the client directly.

Comment: @robsch yea but you still need to have the dependencies installes to create that bundle in the first place.